# Generate and Copy WSDL error in NetBeans 8.2

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8, netbeans-8.2

When I click generate and copy WSDL it returns error like this:

```
ant -f H:\\Projects\\NetBeansProjects\\wsCiscoCallBack\\nbproject\\build-
impl.xml wsgen-CiscoCallBack
init:
deps-module-jar:
deps-ear-jar:
deps-jar:
library-inclusion-in-archive:
library-inclusion-in-manifest:
Compiling 3 source files to H:\Projects\NetBeansProjects\wsCiscoCallBack\build\web\WEB-INF\classes
wsgen-init:
wsgen-CiscoCallBack:
JAX-WS RI 2.2.11-b150120.1832
command line: **wsgen"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre\bin\java.exe" -d H:\Projects\NetBeansProjects\wsCiscoCallBack\build\generated-sources\jax-ws -Xendorsed -keep -s H:\Projects\NetBeansProjects\wsCiscoCallBack\build\generated-sources\jax-ws -verbose -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\lib\tools.jar;H:\Projects\NetBeansProjects\wsCiscoCallBack\build\web\WEB-INF\classes;C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\modules\webservices-osgi.jar;C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\modules\endorsed\webservices-api-osgi.jar;C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\modules\jaxb-osgi.jar;C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\modules\endorsed\jaxb-api.jar" -wsdl -r H:\Projects\NetBeansProjects\wsCiscoCallBack\build\generated-sources\jax-ws\resources ws.CiscoCallBack**
H:\Projects\NetBeansProjects\wsCiscoCallBack\nbproject\jaxws-build.xml:26: Error starting wsgen: class com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool
```

I've read NetBeans forums and they said something like this:

> For Netbeans 8.2 and Windows 7, the default ant settings for Netbeans
>   are incorrect; if you check the error, you will find that wsgen"C....
>   are not seperated.  A space should be between those two i.e. wsgen
>   "C..... So either fix the ant settings or copy the command and correct
>   it before running it again.

I understood that i should add space between them. But how can i add this space in NetBeans 8.2? Please anyone can help me. I'm struggling with it almost four hours.

Answer (score 0):

You got to open your operative system prompt and change directory to your JDK/bin folder, unless you added the JDK/bin path to system path.

Then on Netbeans copy all the row with wsgen wrong path.

Back on the prompt and paste the wrong row, add the space between **wsgen** and **"C:...** , then go to the end of the code you pasted and press ENTER.

If all is OK wsdl and xsd files will be added at your project inside Netbeans.